# OnPrimaryClipChangedListener not working

Tags: java, android, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboardmanager

This is my code for implementation of OnPrimaryCLipChangedListener:

```
public class PrimaryClipChangedListener implements OnPrimaryClipChangedListener {

@Override
public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("RAJATH", "copyclip reached");                    
        }

}
```

My service which register the listener:

```
package com.example.tryservice;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyService extends Service{
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("RAJATH", "Service Reached");
    ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);       
    cb.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new PrimaryClipChangedListener());
    return 0;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

I have an activity that starts this service. The purpose of this code is to listen to clipboard changes in the background. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you got a solution on this? I Met the same issue on my 4.3 device. No crashes but no any log also. Like it is not registered at all. But same code seems to be working on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly doesn't work? There is a bug in Android 4.3 where the system crashes if you listen for OnPrimaryClipChangedListener callbacks.

Comment: I don't receive callbacks. I don't get the log messages printed.

Comment: Does you system break... which version of Android are you running?

Comment: System doens't crash. The service is shown in the settings->apps->running